# Set the Image path for Windows application?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

Am having an image in my Project-solution and i need to set the image dynamically?
for a picture box of winforms in vb.net?

> how can i work with that.?

pls help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Right click on the Project > Properties then select Resources
2. Click Images and Add an Image (eg Employee)

Then in code you can set the picturebox's image property like this:

```
Me.picBox.Image = Global.NameSpace.Properties.Resources.Employee
```

NameSpace is obvisouly the namespace of your solution. HTH